# Allow screen to turn off for fullscreen android app

Tags: android, fullscreen, wakelock

I have tried several published solutions to try and turn the screen off in android, including:

```
getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

Which results in no change.

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams param = getWindow().getAttributes();
param.screenBrightness = 0;
param.flags |= LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON;
getWindow().setAttributes(param);
```

Which results in a slightly dimmed screen (on Android 4.2.1)

```
//Release all previously held WakeLocks
if (mWakeLock.isHeld()) {
    mWakeLock.release();
}
//Then acquire a partial wake lock (which should allow the display to turn off)
PowerManager powerMan = (PowerManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
mWakeLock = powerMan.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "Partial WakeLock");
mWakeLock.acquire();
```

Which results in no change.

And finally, the illegal

```
PowerManager powerMan = (PowerManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
powerMan.goToSleep(1000);
```

which clearly doesn't work because:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DEVICE_POWER" />
```

is not permissible (to non-system apps).

I am assuming these problems are because my app is `android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme"`.

Are there any workable solutions to allow a fullscreen app to go to sleep without sacrificing the wonderful fullscreen theme?

Comment: "Fullscreen" has nothing to do with keeping the screen on. If you do not force the screen to stay on, it will turn off of its own accord, based upon the user's settings.

Comment: The screen is set to 15sec timeout, stay awake while plugged in is off, and android:keepScreenOn="true" is nowhere to be found in any of the XML docs.

I'm not sure what else could be the problem :/

Comment: What device are you testing this on?

Comment: Nexus 7 and Nexus 10. Both running 4.2.1, and both behave the same way.

Comment: I assumed it was the FullscreenTheme causing the issues, because the device goes to sleep automatically normally. Other bits of info - I'm running an `AsyncTask` which updates a Bitmap in an image view before sleeping using `SystemClock.sleep(10000);`, but all on the `AsyncTask`'s `doInBackground` method. The app is essentially a slideshow of images that I would like to turn on when I arrive in the office, and then turn off when I leave (automatically). I know I could push the power button - but that's not cool :)

Comment: If you create a sample project that reproduces the error, I'll take a look at it. Perhaps there's something floating around your custom theme that is the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the interest! The crazy thing is that it isn't even a custom theme! It's the default one you get when you create a new activity, and select 'FullscreenActivity'. FYI, I do know that when you select that type of activity, the layout XML includes `android:keepScreenOn="true"` in the default TextView. I have deleted this... I will try start the project again from scratch, and see what happens. If it's still an issue, I'll include a github link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After writing a simple answer to try and post to @CommonsWare, I found that the problem didn't persist.

I combed through my code several times, and still didn't find anything which would cause the screen to stay awake. I rewrote the entire app from scratch (always a good exercise, ending up with much cleaner logic), and the problem disappeared.

Lesson learnt - if all else fails, re-write everything again. It's a useful exercise in itself :)